# How to mark fields and write next to them in arrays, without making it a new field?

Tags: color, arrays

I want to do this (at the "S")
[image]
but I have no idea how to do it without making it a new field and thus making new borders, my code looks like this:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12p]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, automata, backgrounds, positioning, fit,petri}
\setlength\parindent{0pt}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\colorlet{temp}{blue}

\title{Hausaufgabe 22, CYK-Algorithmus}
\date{\today}

\begin{document}
    
    \maketitle
    
    \section*{Nr. 2}
    \subsection*{a)}
    \subsubsection*{abcabcca}
    
    \[
    \setlength\extrarowheight{2pt}
    \begin{array}{|*{8}{c|}}
        \cline{1-8}
        {\color{temp} a} & {\color{temp} b} & {\color{temp} c} & {\color{temp} a} & {\color{temp} b} & {\color{temp} c} & {\color{temp} c} & {\color{temp} a} \\
        \cline{1-8}
        A & B/Y/X & C & A & B/Y/X & C & C & A \\
        \cline{1-8}
        V & Y/X & - & V & Y/X & Y/X & - \\
        \cline{1-7}
        V & W & - & V & X/Y & W \\
        \cline{1-6}
        - & - & - & V/X/Y/ & W \\
        \cline{1-5}
        - & - & - & W \\
        \cline{1-4}
        - & X/Y & - \\
        \cline{1-3}
        V & - \\
        \cline{1-2}
        S \\
        \cline{1-1}
    \end{array}
    \]
    
\end{document}
```

I tried do a workaround and fill the field with \cellcolor \rowcolor and \Block[draw, fill = blue!15, rounded-corners] and then write it below, but not even colouring works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using `\mathrlap` from the `mathtools` package?

This works because the contents inside `\mathrlap{}` are not considered to have width (lap in right), so the table will not be influenced.

> P.S. `mathtools` auto loads `amsmath`.

**EDIT**: To highlight cell with `\cellcolor{}`, you need to load `colortbl.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12p]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{mathtools} % <- replace amsmath
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{colortbl} % <- use this
\setlength\parindent{0pt}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\colorlet{temp}{blue}

\title{Hausaufgabe 22, CYK-Algorithmus}
\date{\today}

\begin{document}
    
    \maketitle
    
    \section*{Nr. 2}
    \subsection*{a)}
    \subsubsection*{abcabcca}
    
    \[
    \setlength\extrarowheight{2pt}
    \begin{array}{|*{8}{c|}}
        \cline{1-8}
        {\color{temp} a} & {\color{temp} b} & {\color{temp} c} & {\color{temp} a} & {\color{temp} b} & {\color{temp} c} & {\color{temp} c} & {\color{temp} a} \\
        \cline{1-8}
        A & B/Y/X & C & A & B/Y/X & C & C & A \\
        \cline{1-8}
        V & Y/X & - & V & Y/X & Y/X & - \\
        \cline{1-7}
        V & W & - & V & X/Y & W \\
        \cline{1-6}
        - & - & - & V/X/Y/ & W \\
        \cline{1-5}
        - & - & - & W \\
        \cline{1-4}
        - & X/Y & - \\
        \cline{1-3}
        V & - \\
        \cline{1-2}
        \cellcolor{green} S \mathrlap{\quad\Rightarrow abcabcca\in L(g'')} \\
        \cline{1-1}
    \end{array}
    \]
    
\end{document}
```

[image: Result]